# Can someone help me understand viewport, scissor, renderarea, framebuffer size, attachment size in vulkan?

Tags: graphics, vulkan

Just as the question title, I'm a bit confused with those stuff, especially viewport and render area. AFAIK, viewport is used in VS stage, while render area is used in FS stage, if the viewport is smaller than the render area, what will happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The viewport specifies how the normalized device coordinates are transformed into the pixel coordinates of the framebuffer.

Scissor is the area where you can render, this is similar to viewport in that regard but changing the scissor rectangle doesn't affect the coordinates.

RenderArea is the area of the framebuffer that will be changed by the renderpass. This lets the implementation know that not the entire frame buffer will be changed and gives it opportunity to optimize by for example not including some tiles in a tile based architecture. It is the application's responsibility that no rendering happens outside that area, for example by making sure the scissor rects are always fully contained within the renderArea.

Framebuffer size and attachment size are related in that the attachments must be at least as large as the framebuffer.

> if viewport is small than render area, what will happen?

Nothing special, the render commands will render within the viewport. The other way around (render area smaller than the viewport) will result in undefined values in the framebuffer.

Comment: To add to this you can use multiple draw calls with different render areas and have things like split screen or picture in picture.  This is really useful for debugging.